# get_the_post_thumbnail() returns nothing?

Tags: post-thumbnails

Here's my code:

```
    function widget($args, $options) {
    extract($args);

    global $post;
    $post_type = $options['post_type'];
    $num_of_posts = $options['limit'];

    // Create a new instance
    $second_query = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type' => "$post_type",
                        'posts_per_page' => "$num_of_posts",
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                    ) ); 

    // The Loop
    if ($second_query->have_posts()) :
      while( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post();
          $content .= '<span><a href="' .get_permalink(). '">' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</a></span>';
          $content .= '<div>' .get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(290,290)). '</div>';
          $content .= '<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>';
      endwhile; else :
          $content = '<p>No ' . $options['post_type'] . 's found.</p>';
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $title = "<h3>" . $options['title'] . "</h3>";

    echo $before_widget.$title.$content.$after_widget;
}
```

Everything displays fine except the thumbnail :-\

Comment: Add `global $post` before the code.

Comment: kaiser: it's already part of the code...

Comment: Nice. But I can't see it anywhere. Guessing what code _could_ be there is the opposite of funny... How about posting your _whole_ code.

Comment: @kaiser: I'have updated my post.. pasted the whole function..

Comment: BTW, thumbnail support is already enabled in `functions.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try just get_the_post_thumbnail(). Leave the $post->ID out of it.

Edit: Never mind, get_the_post_thumbnail does require the ID. I'd use the get_the_ID() function instead of $post->ID, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: didn't work. Even tried echo'ing it.

Comment: Dumb question: Does the post in question even *have* a thumbnail?

Comment: Dumb question too: I placed an image into the post in the editor panel, will wp use that as the thumbnail? Or I have to do something custom to add a thumbnail to the post? :-\

Comment: Images placed in the editor aren't counted as post thumbnails, there's a seperate metabox(typically on the righthand side of the editor screen) for adding a featured/thumbnail image to the post. If you don't see that metabox check under screen options.

Comment: Yes, an image in the post isn't the thumbnail. There's a special metabox on the Edit Post page called Featured Image where you can select an image for the thumbnail. Check the Screen options if you don't see it.